# How to update only selected files with eclipse git?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I found I must update all the files to my workspace when I got changes from others. Previously I have used SVN , I can use update function to update selected files, but how about git? Must I update all other changes to my local workspace before I commit my changes?

Regards,
Hua Jie

Comment: You mean pushing? You are working locally and you can do all youre work - indeed commiting - and before you can push to a remote, you have been committed youre work? I think Chapter 2 will help you: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: Hi , I mean get the remote update to my local. However I don't want to update all to my local. Instead I want to update partially.